# How to register a generic interface using TinyIOC

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inversion-of-control, tinyioc

Suppose I have a generic interface and a generic implementation. How do I register all usages?

Specifically, I have the following (reduced for simplicity):

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : TableEntity
{
    T GetById(string partitionKey, string rowKey);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Update(string partitionKey, string rowKey, Action<T> updateAction);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
}


public class AzureRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : TableEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Do I need to register all implementations one by one, like so:

```
container.Register<IRepository<Entity1>, AzureRepository<Entity1>>();
container.Register<IRepository<Entity2>, AzureRepository<Entity2>>();
container.Register<IRepository<Entity3>, AzureRepository<Entity3>>();
...
```

Or is there a shorter way?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/issues/8

Comment: No - In this example, it registers all IRepository dependencies (IR<Entity1>, IR<Entity2>, etc..) as AzureRepository<Entity1>.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior (in v1.2) - but that clearly is a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, TinyIoC has a bug in the resolution of Open Generics - it doesn't keep the resolved instances with different type parameters apart, and as all registrations are implicitly done with `.AsSingleton()` by default, it always returns the first instance of the generic type that was resolved for all subsequent resolution requests.

Due to this, the following doesn't work:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(AzureRepository<>));
```

There is a workaround, however - make the registration transient:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(AzureRepository<>)).AsMultiInstance();
```

This will create a new instance for each resolution request and properly honor the type parameter. The downside of this is that you also get a new instance each time you request the interface with a type parameter that has previously been resolved.

**Edit**

Confirmed. Open Generics resolution does use the `SingletonFactory` that once it has created an instance will always return that for subsequent resolutions. It doesn't know or care about Generics. For this to work properly, a `GenericSingletonFactory` would be required that does not only keep a single instance but a dictionary keyed by the concrete type to be resolved.

Alright, that wasn't even that hard to fix. I just don't understand enough about it yet to be sure that it's really all correct.